# Qt multi-process build from source fails with error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I build qt from source on Windows. Here is the minimum reproducible example:

```
setlocal

@echo off

set DOWNLOAD_URL=https://qt-mirror.dannhauer.de/official_releases/qt/5.12/5.12.12/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.12.zip

For %%A in ("%DOWNLOAD_URL%") do (
    set FILENAME=%%~nxA
)

set WORK_DIR=%~dp0\qt
set SRC_DIR=%WORK_DIR%\src
set BUILD_DIR=%WORK_DIR%\build
set OUTPUT_DIR=%WORK_DIR%\out

rmdir /S /Q "%BUILD_DIR%"
rmdir /S /Q "%OUTPUT_DIR%"
mkdir "%BUILD_DIR%"
mkdir "%OUTPUT_DIR%"

if not exist "%WORK_DIR%\%FILENAME%" (
    curl -fL "%DOWNLOAD_URL%" --output "%WORK_DIR%\%FILENAME%"
    rmdir /S /Q %SRC_DIR%
)

if not exist "%SRC_DIR%" (
    mkdir %SRC_DIR%
    tar -vxf "%WORK_DIR%\%FILENAME%" -C %SRC_DIR% --strip-components 1
)

cd "%BUILD_DIR%"
call %SRC_DIR%/configure.bat ^
                -prefix %OUTPUT_DIR% ^
                -debug-and-release ^
                -opensource ^
                -confirm-license ^
                -make libs ^
                -nomake examples ^
                -nomake tests ^
                -qt-freetype ^
                -qt-harfbuzz ^
                -qt-pcre ^
                -qt-zlib ^
                -qt-libjpeg ^
                -qt-libpng ^
                -plugin-sql-sqlite ^
                -no-cups ^
                -no-evdev ^
                -no-glib ^
                -no-icu ^
                -no-opengl ^
                -no-xcb ^
                -no-xcb-xlib ^
                -no-xkbcommon ^
                -skip qt3d ^
                -skip qtandroidextras ^
                -skip qtcanvas3d ^
                -skip qtcharts ^
                -skip qtconnectivity ^
                -skip qtdatavis3d ^
                -skip qtdeclarative ^
                -skip qtdoc ^
                -skip qtgamepad ^
                -skip qtgraphicaleffects ^
                -skip qtimageformats ^
                -skip qtlocation ^
                -skip qtmacextras ^
                -skip qtmultimedia ^
                -skip qtpurchasing ^
                -skip qtquickcontrols ^
                -skip qtquickcontrols2 ^
                -skip qtscript ^
                -skip qtscxml ^
                -skip qtsensors ^
                -skip qtserialbus ^
                -skip qtserialport ^
                -skip qtspeech ^
                -skip qtsvg ^
                -skip qttranslations ^
                -skip qtvirtualkeyboard ^
                -skip qtwayland ^
                -skip qtwebchannel ^
                -skip qtwebengine ^
                -skip qtwebsockets ^
                -skip qtwebview ^
                -skip qtwinextras ^
                -skip qtx11extras ^
                -skip qtxmlpatterns

if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
    echo.&echo Configuration failed!
    exit /b 1
)

jom

if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
    echo.&echo Build failed!
    exit /b 1
)
```

After some time of building phase I get the error: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` The error happens at different points of the build, i.e. it looks like it is not tied to a particular file.

I tried:

- to have only `-release` instead of `-debug-and-release`
- instead of `jom`, to have

```
set CL=/MP
nmake
```

- to have `-mp` option and call `nmake`
- I also tried to download different versions of Qt. e.g. Qt 5.15.2
- I tried to revert my `Windows 10 Pro 21H2 19044.1826` VM to an earlier snapshot.

None of those helped. The only thing that helped is to hum only one building process: i.e., just to have `nmake` and that's it (i.e., without `CL=/MP` or `-mp` option). But I don't like this, as it allows to use only one core for the build.

I have found this bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-66059?attachmentViewMode=list but it does not help. It is closed, but I still get the error. How can I fix this error? I am not the only person who builds Qt from source, I guess, but I cannot find any solution on the Internet. I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: First things: Disable all anti virus and similar software from the source and build directories. Thats a classic reason for things like this.

Comment: @MikeVine My VM is quite "clean" in this sense. I do not install any anti-virus programs, as I use the system just to build and test an app that I write.